# Sample from custom distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, sampling

I have implemented an alternate parameterization of the negative binomial distribution in R, like so (also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)):

```
nb = function(n, l, a){
  first = choose((n + a - 1), a-1)
  second = (l/(l+a))^n
  third = (a/(l+a))^a
  return(first*second*third)
}
```

Where n is the count, lambda is the mean, and a is the overdispersion term.

**I would like to draw random samples from this distribution** in order to validate my implementation of a negative binomial mixture model, but am not sure how to go about doing this.  The CDF of this function isn't easily defined, so I considered trying rejection sampling as discussed [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-simple-explanation-of-rejection-sampling-in-r/), but that didn't work either (and I'm not sure why- the article says to first draw from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1, but I want my NB distribution to model integer counts...I'm not sure if I understand this approach fully.)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could:

1) Draw a uniform random number between zero and one.

2) Numerically integrate the probability density function (this is really just a sum, since the distribution is discrete and lower-bounded at zero).

3) Whichever value in your integration takes the cdf past your random number, that's your random draw.

So all together, do something like the following:

```
r <- runif(1,0,1)
cdf <- 0
i <- -1
while(cdf < r){
  i <- i+1
  p <- PMF(i)
  cdf <- cdf + p
}
```

Where PMF(i) is the probability mass over a count of i, as specified by the parameters of the distribution.  The value of i when this while-loop finishes is your sample.

Comment: This seems similar to the rejection sampling method I linked to in my post (maybe I'm mistaken)?  But I will give this a try.

Comment: This is very different from rejection sampling.  Rejection sampling works by proposing a sample, calculating the likelihood, and accepting the sample with probability proportional to the likelihood.  (The uniform distribution from zero to one crops up in the linked rejection sampling example because the beta-distribution is defined over that interval, so that's the interval that the proposed samples come from).  
My answer works by finding the sample that corresponds to a given value of the cdf, where that given value is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (the endpoints of the cdf).

Comment: The point here is that doing this integration (sum) with this stopping criterion computes the inverse cdf.  And because the distribution is discrete, the computation is exact.  It's not a closed form, so you'll pay an efficiency price if you need a huge number of draws.  But it should still be pretty fast, particularly when the expected value of the distribution you're sampling from is relatively small.

Comment: Jacob, thank you for your detailed answer!  I used your method and obtained a sampled density that looks quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look up the Uniform distribution as well as the Universality of the Uniform. You can do exactly what you want by passing a uniformly distributed variable to the inverse CDF of the NB Binomial and what you will get is set of points sampled from your NB Binomial distribution.

EDIT: I see that the negative binomial has a CDF which has no closed form inverse. My second recommendation would be to scrap your function and use a built-in:

```
library(MASS)
rnegbin(n, mu = n, theta = stop("'theta' must be specified"))
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but I'd like to keep my function since this formulation of the NB is what is typically used for gene expression/read counts, which is the system I'm trying to model.

Comment: Well I recommend you start searching for a closed form expression for your representation and using the Universality of the Uniform then.

Comment: You don't really need a closed form in this case, unless efficiency is a major concern.  It's easy enough to compute the inverse CDF numerically.  And since the distribution is discrete and bounded at zero, the computation is exact.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to test and so speed is not the issue, the
inversion method, as mentioned by others, is probably the way to go.

For a discrete random variable, it requires a simple while loop. See 
[Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/) by L. Devroye, chapter 3, p. 85.