# R How to sample from an interrupted upside down bell curve

Tags: r, random, sampling

I've asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886064/how-to-sample-from-an-upside-down-bell-curve) before which successfully received an answer. Now I want to sample values from an upside down bell curve but exclude a range of values that fall in the middle of it like shown on the picture below:
[image]

I have this code currently working:

```
min <- 1
max <- 20
q <- min + (max-min)*rbeta(10000, 0.5, 0.5)
```

How may I adapt it to achieve the desired output?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941091/sample-from-custom-distribution-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want a sample of 10,000 from your distribution but don't want any numbers between 5 and 15 in your sample. Why not just do:

```
q <- min + (max-min)*rbeta(50000, 0.5, 0.5); 
q <- q[!(q > 5 & q < 15)][1:10000]
```

Which gives you this:

```
hist(q)
```

[image]

But still has the correct size:

```
length(q)
#> [1] 10000
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan! I'll test tomorrow. How may I adapt the solution if I want to run it row-wise over data frame? So currently my actual code is generating a random number by row based on the minimum and maximum values of 2 existing columns: 'Table$randomColumn<- Table$MinCol + (Table$MaxCol-Table$MinCol)*rbeta(nrow(Table), 0.5, 0.5)'

Comment: You could use an iterative approach @nba2020. Something like `Table$randomColumn <- rep(NA, nrow(Table)); while(any(is.na(Table$randomColumn))) { subset <- which(is.na(Table$randomColumn)); Table$randomColumn[subset] <- Table$MinCol[subset] + (Table$MaxCol[subset]-Table$MinCol[subset])*rbeta(length(subset), 0.5, 0.5); Table$randomColumn[Table$randomColumn > 5 & Table$randomColumn < 15] <- NA;}`

Comment: Thanks the answer worked, I'll ask a separate question for the row-wise application.

Answer (score 0):

An "upside-down bell curve" compared to the normal distribution, with the exclusion of a certain interval, can be sampled using the following algorithm. I write it in pseudocode because I'm not familiar with R. I adapted it from another [answer I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881661/815724).

Notice that this sampler samples in a truncated interval (here, the interval [`x0`, `x1`], with the exclusion of [`x2`, `x3`]) because it's not possible for an upside-down bell curve extended to infinity to integrate to 1 (which is one of the requirements for a probability density).

In the pseudocode, `RNDU01()` is a uniform(0, 1) random number.

```
x0pdf = 1-exp(-(x0*x0))
x1pdf = 1-exp(-(x1*x1))
ymax = max(x0pdf, x1pdf)
while true
  # Choose a random x-coordinate
  x=RNDU01()*(x1-x0)+x0
  # Choose a random y-coordinate
  y=RNDU01()*ymax
  # Return x if y falls within PDF
  if (x<x2 or x>x3) and y < 1-exp(-(x*x)): return x
end
```